# Display Content if Meta Checkbox is checked?

Tags: metabox, query

Basically i have a custom post with a custom metabox, with a checkbox inside it.

If you check the box i want something (styled box) to appear within the post loop.

If not checked the box doesn't appear...

I have the following in my template page..

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'books','posts_per_page' => '-1') ); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rw_title_block', true ); ?>

<?php if( checked( $meta, 1, false ) ) : ?>

  check box is checked to display stuff like... <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endif ?>     

not checked ignore this stuff...

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query() ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The metabox functions code (this seems to display fine in the admin.)

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id'         => 'test_metabox',
'title'      => 'Test Metabox',
'pages'      => array( 'books', ),
'context'    => 'normal',
'priority'   => 'high',
'show_names' => false, 
'fields'     => array(

    array(
        'name' => 'Test Checkbox',
        'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
        'id'   => $prefix . 'title_block',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
    ),

),
);
```

Thank you for any help, it would be a life saver.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

First make the custom post query with the WP_Query, and then we get the metadata by get_post_meta. Checkboxses are saved as boolean, that means either true or false. So make a check in the loop if checked or not (1=true, 0=false).

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type'      => 'books',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

    $checke_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_title_block', true );
    ?>

    <?php if( $checked_meta ) {
       echo 'Do stuff here if checked';
    } else {
       echo the_title();
    }
    ?>

   <?php 
   endwhile;
   // Reset Post Data
   wp_reset_postdata();

   ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, in fact its only showing the content from the page its on. Rather than the custom post type, this is a template attached to a page and its only showing the page content... any ideas, never usually have this problem displaying custom posts on a page..?

Comment: the problem with your code is that you don't check if the custom post have post, you only check if "post (have_posts)" instead of your own loop ( $loop->have_posts) so thats why you get the page content. look at my updated answer on the $the_query

Comment: I found this worked...http://pastebin.com/TX21G3iM